# I need to mock this using jest-fetch-mock

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, fetch, react-testing-library

I cant find examples containing then after fetch i need to  mock this in typescript using react-test-mock

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
    fetch(
      `${config.baseUrl}/${config.apiVersion}/countapplications`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        tokenizeStatus(data);
        setStatusResult(data);
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

The console of fetch -

```
 console.log(fetch(
      `${config.baseUrl}/${config.apiVersion}/countapplications`
    ).then((res) => res.json()));
```

gives -

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(5)
0: {status: "Incomplete", count: 14}
1: {status: "Submitted", count: 6}
2: {status: "Interview", count: 3}
3: {status: "Pre-onboard", count: 0}
4: {status: "Offer", count: 1}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete code.

Comment: @slideshowp2 i dont think any other code is needed to write the mock

Comment: Can I remove `useEffect`, `tokenizeStatus` and `setStatusResult` functions? Do you only need to mock `fetch` correctly?

Comment: @slideshowp2 i dont think useeffect will effect anything but i do need tokenizeStatus and setStatusResult